# Why, specifically, is George Asanidze's record not 181kg?

Tags: weightlifting

Do the official olympic weightlifting rules really not count 1kg increments? Why? Seems like unit and fractional weights should count.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnR2JoCDfXs&t=6m6s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video shows the European Championships. So it simply wasn't an Olympic competition in that video. He achieved the Olympic record in the [Sydney 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_weightlifting) games with 180 kg, so that number is actually correct. And as you can see on that list every kg counts, so 1 kg increments are possible and achievable.

An Olympic record is only recognized as such if it was achieved in the Olympics, even if it is the world record (or was in this case, since the world record has been beaten in 2007 when [Andrei Rybakou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_Olympic_weightlifting) lifted 187 kg in the World Championships).

Comment: So the record for 85kg is 187kg?

Comment: This [site](http://www.iwf.net/results/olympic-records/) is not up to date.

Comment: @twoblacklinesinthemiddle No, *both* are valid records. 180 kg is the current Olympic record and 187 kg is the world record. The Olympics have their own record and only match the world record when it was achieved in the Olympic games. If the world record is higher than the Olympic record it was simply achieved in another tournament, such as the World Championships in this particular case.